# Keyboard navigation is not working on mui x datepicker component when I use it on popup or modal

Tags: reactjs, web-frontend, mui-x, mui-x-date-picker

Keyboard navigation is not working in mui x Datepicker component when I am using it on popup or modal
I can able to open calendar with keyboard enter key but after opening calendar I am not able to navigate through dates via keyboard

I tried different approaches like to get focus on that Calendar so that keyboard navigation will work but somehow it is not happening

Comment: Same component if I use on page then keyboard navigation is working